# Search a word in a string of characters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hello guys I have two strings in Python:

```
str1 = "honey"
str2 = "eeehanoey"
```

I want that the program returns me `True` if all the letters in `str1` are in `str2` and `False` otherwise, I have alredy tried with `in` but doesn't works, return me `False`.

Thank you

Comment: How do you treat duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with sets, if duplicate counts don't matter.

```
>>> s1 = set(str1)
>>> s2 = set(str2)
>>> s1.intersection(s2) == s1
True
```

Alternatively (slower)...

```
>>> s1 = ''.join(sorted(str1))
>>> s2 = ''.join(sorted(str2))
>>> s1 in s2
True
```

---

Update: Adding a method to handle duplicates too.

```
from collections import Counter

def match(str1, str2):
    c1 = Counter(str1)
    c2 = Counter(str2)

    for c in c1:
        if c not in c2 or c1[c] > c2[c]:
            return False

    return True
```

Output:

```
>>> match("honey", "eeehanoey")
True
>>> match("rapture", "aaepprut")
False
```

Comment: Clever and clean. +!

Comment: I'm already try with set but with others word give me False instead of True

Comment: @LuisMiguel Well, you obviously didn't try it like this, because this works.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah but the problem is when you have like this `str1 = "rapture"` and `str2 = "aaepprut"`, because there's two 'r' in the str1 and in the str2 just one, that's why is `False`.

Comment: @LuisMiguel `>>> str1 = "rapture" ;
>>> str2 = "aaepprut" ;
>>> s1 = set(str1) ;
>>> s2 = set(str2) ;
>>> s1.intersection(s2) == s1 ;
True`

Comment: Should it be false or true?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sorry men I get confused, should be `False`.

Comment: @LuisMiguel Okay, edited my answer with a new solution.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ IT WORKS! The second solution is the good one, thank very much.

Comment: @LuisMiguel Cheers. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

**This will do it:**

```
def lettersmatch(str1, str2):

    #loop through each letter in str1
    for letter in str1:
        #if this letter is not in the second string, return false
        if not letter in str2:
            return False

    #if we get here, the letters match
    return True
```

---

**Note:** This assumes that "aacd" and "acd" should be considered equal. (Basically, this assumes that duplicates are unimportant.)

Comment: It works but when a I have `str1 = "rapture"` and `str2 = "aaepprut"`, because there's two 'r' in the `str1` and in the `str2` just one, anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
all([c in str2 for c in str1])
```

Or if you care about repeats, this will do it:

```
all([str2.count(c) <= str1.count(c) for c in str1])

>>> str1 = "honey"
>>> str2 = "eeehanoey"
>>> str3 = "hooney"
>>> all([str1.count(c) <= str2.count(c) for c in str1])
True
>>> all([str3.count(c) <= str2.count(c) for c in str3])
False
```

There are probably some other ways to go about it as well, but these one-liners are not too bad.